Complex Numbers - Find the minimum value of ${|{z^2-1}|+|{z^2+1}|}$
Question - If ${|z|=1}$ and ${z\neq \pm1}$, then the minimum value of ${|z|+|\frac{z^2-1}{z}|+|\frac{z^2+1}{z}|}$
_
Tried a couple ways to solve this question. The essence of the question is basically minimum value of ${|{z^2-1}|+|{z^2+1}|}$. I tried to write $z$ as ${a+ib}$ and then expand ${z^2-1}$ and ${z^2+1}$ (and we know ${a^2+b^2=1}$) but that doesn't really seem to get me anywhere. How do you solve this...
The answer is 3 btw.

Welcome to MSE. From How to ask a good question: "Your question should be clear without the title.
After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title."

@jjagmath I'm sorry. This is my first post. Should I edit it? Is this fine?

Please, edit it.

@jjagmath Is it alright now?

Also, if you need help with MathJax you can find it here, so you can avoid writing things like $+-1$ or $ a =/= b$

Thanks. Is it possible to see the title when creating question (I only see it in its barebones form, not what it comes out as). I mistakenly assumed that those were the right syntax. I was lazy. Should have checked.

For what it's worth, virtually every MathSE posted question that I have seen, that followed this article on MathSE protocol has been upvoted rather than downvoted.  I am not necessarily advocating this protocol.  Instead, I am merely stating a fact: if you scrupulously follow the linked article, skipping/omitting nothing, you virtually guarantee a positive response.

Triangle inequality: $|z^2-1| + |z^2+1| = |z^2-1| + |-1-z^2| \geq |z^2-1-1-z^2| = |-2|$. Then you can verify this bound as a minimum with $z=i$.

Solve it geometrically.
First off, $|z|=1$ so your expression reduces to $1+|z^2-1|+|z^2+1|$. Recall that $|u/v|=|u|/|v|$.
Now with $|z|=1$, $z^2$ will lie on the unit circle and its summed distance to the dianetrically opposite points $\pm1$ must be greater than or equal to the diameter of two units. Equality is achieved when $z^2=\pm1$, which among allowed values implies $z=\pm i$. So for those $z$ values we achieve the minimum value of $2$ for $|z^2-1|+|z^2+1|$, hence $3$ for the minimum of the original function follows.


Oh, sorry, I forgot about that.

Observe that $2 = |2z^2| = |(z^2-1)+(z^2+1)| \leq |z^2-1| + |z^2+1|$ and that $z=i$ achieves this minimum.
The final result follows from your observation.

WLOG, $z=\cos t+i\sin t$
$p=|z^2+1|=|\cos2t+i\sin2t+1|=2|\cos t|$
$q=|z^2-1|=\cdots=2|\sin t|$
$(p+q)^2=4+4|\sin2t|$
Finally $0\le|\sin2t|\le1$
$\implies\sqrt4\le p+q \le \sqrt{4+4}$
